# Deleting back to back substrings from a string but not all occurences - c#

Tags: c#, regex, string, substring

I have a string like:

> "Water Water ASDF FDSA"

as well as strings like:

> "Water Water ASDF FDSA Water"

I need to only remove the first instance of back to back substrings so that these two cases become:

> "Water ASDF FDSA" and "Water ASDF FDSA Water"

What I tried to do:

```
        List<string> substrings = FindSubstrings(returnString);
        IEnumerable<string> duplicateItems = from x in substrings
                             group x by x into grouped
                             where grouped.Count() > 1
                             select grouped.Key;
```

So I have a seperate FindSubstrings method that returns a List that contains all the substrings from the original string. I then (from online I found) a way to detect duplicates which a list of them get placed in a IEnumerable.

Is the best way to go about this then to do something like:

```
       for (int i = 0; i < substrings.Count; i++)
        {
           //if duplicateItems contains the substring and substring[i+1] is also the same item, then remove it)
        }
```

The issue was I cant get the string from duplicateItems if it contains more than one duplicate substring becuase there is no indexing over an IEnumerable. Any ideas on the best way to do this?

Comment: 1) Do you have `Water Water Water ASDF FDSA`? And if yes, what output do you wish to get? `Water Water ASDF FDSA` or `Water ASDF FDSA`? And 2) if you have `Text Water Water ASDF FDSA`, should it be turned into `Text Water ASDF FDSA`?

Comment: Water Water Water ASDF FDSA -> Water ASDF FDSA. Yes

Comment: Then , I guess, you have an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can search using regex:

```
\b(\w+)\s+(?=\1)
```

and replace with empty string.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vJ6fK3/1)

`(?=\1)` is positive lookahead that makes sure that there is a repeat of the word being captured using `(\w+)`.

**Code:**

```
string repl = Regex.Replace(input, @"\b(\w+)\s+(?=\1)", "");
```